# Obtain the Elements of a Collection having the identical subset of Properties using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
List<MyObject> filteredObjects = myObjects.stream()
    .filter(anObject -> 
        Collections.frequency(myObjects, anObject) > 1
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which does the job of getting me the objects from the `Collection` of `MyObject` that occur **more than once**.

I need to modify this code so that it gives me the objects that match one another not according to the `equals()`, but based on a **subset of properties**.

So if `MyObject` has properties: `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

```
public static class MyObject {
    private Foo foo;
    private Bar bar;
    private Baz baz;
    
    // constructor, getters, etc.
}
```

I want the to get the objects that have a corresponding object in the collection with the same values of `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Do you want to check the match on only these two out of three properties or do you want to match at least one of the properties?

Comment: "Which does the job"... sure? Seems like without some collect-stage at the end the stream-filter will do nothing at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom object that encompasses these properties (`foo`, `bar`) that require to match and generate an auxiliary `Map` using such objects as a *key*.

In the code below for conciseness I'm using Java 16 [record](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/language/records.html) to define a *key*, if you're using an earlier JDK version it can be replaced with a class.

```
record Key(Object foo, Object bar) {
    public Key(MyObject o) {
        this(o.getFoo(), o.getBar());
    }
}
```

When you have a Map associating all objects having equal set of properties with the same key on your hands, the only thing left is to filter the values having size greater than `1`.

```
List<MyObject> filteredObjects = myObjects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( // creates an intermediate Map<Key, List<MyObject>>
        Key::new
    ))
    .values().stream()               // Stream<List<MyObject>>
    .filter(list -> list.size() > 1)
    .flatMap(List::stream)           // Stream<MyObject>
    .toList();                       // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList()) for earlier versions
```

In case if you need to preserve the encounter order of objects, you can use another version of the collector [`groupingBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector)) which allows to specify *mapFactory*:

```
Collectors.groupingBy(
    Key::new,
    LinkedHashMap::new,
    Collectors.toList()
)
```

Comment: Nice, but (a) why not define the `record` outside of the stream, and (b) I'd think you should rather flatten the lists instead of just taking the first element, since they are not all equal.

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks, I misread the description (and for that reason used `== 1` instead of `> 1`). Clearly, that's the use case for `flatMap`. Regarding declaring a record outside the stream, sure, we can do it either.

Comment: Did not even see the `== 1` :-). Also, this obviously changes the order of elements... _if_ this is a problem, you might start with the grouping, then map individual elements to size of "their" group, then do a regular stream filter.

Comment: @tobias_k `Did not even see the == 1` it existed only in my brain (and can be observed in the history of the answer).

Comment: @tobias_k I've tackled the potential problem with ordering of elements in the result (see the addition at the very end of the answer).